# the behavior of "const id"

Tags: haskell

I'm working on the 99 Haskell questions and saw a solution for finding the last element of a list:

```
  myLast = foldr1 (const id)
```

the type of `const` is `a -> b -> a` but that of `const id` is `b -> a -> a`
so what's the magic here?

Comment: Just to supplement the answers provided, recall that all functions in Haskell are curried, so `a -> (b -> c)` is the same as `a -> b -> c`

Comment: There's a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680341/what-is-the-purpose-of-const-id-in-this-function), but it has a more situational answer, which might be clearer, depending on your thought process.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The type of `id` is `c->c`; it just returns the same thing it is given.

The type of `const` is `a->b->a`. In `const id`, `a` becomes `c->c`, so the type of const in this case becomes:

```
(c->c) -> b -> (c->c)
```

Now that you have applied this const function, i.e. you have passed `id` to it, then you are left with `b -> (c->c)`.

*PS*: The type of `const const id` is `a->b->a`, and the type of `const const const id` is `b->a->a`, and so on!

Comment: No wonder, as `const foo bar = foo`. Note also that `const id` is the same as `flip const`, or `flip const flip const flip const flip const id const id id` ;)

Comment: And, of course, `ap` and `const` are the only two functions you need to compute anything.  (That's the `ap` from the reader monad.)

Comment: @luqui True, with a type checker you'll need some newtype wrapper or similar.

Comment: maybe one should open a new question to list such little, funny, but powerful functions being used in real case

Comment: b -> (c->c) in this case means: id b  (thought I would share, took me a while to get my head around.)

Answer (score 24):

No magic. The definition of `const` is:

```
const :: a -> b -> a
const x y = x
```

And the definition of `id` is:

```
id :: a -> a
id x = x
```

So `const id` is just `\y -> id`, a function that always returns `id`. And if `id` is just `\x -> x` then `const id` must be the same as `\y -> \x -> x`. Ergo, it has type `b -> (a -> a)`.

`const id` can also be written `flip const`. Since `const` is `\x -> \y -> x`, then `flip const` takes the arguments in the opposite order, `\y -> \x -> x`, which is the same as `const id`.

Answer (score 10):

Here's my understanding of how this works.

This is the simplest explanation I could think of, I tried (on purpose) to avoid any potentially confusing concepts or words.

An important concept to keep in mind is partial application.

The way I understand this is, that in Haskell we can “fix” one of the parameters of the function to a known value, so now the function accepts one less parameter.

Recap:  the type of const is:

```
const :: a -> b -> a
```

As a simpler example, let's “fix” the first parameter to be (+)

```
let f = const (+)
```

Now that we've fixed the first parameter of const, “f” is a function which accepts only a single parameter.
But since const always return its first parameter, which we've fixed, it means that whatever we pass to “f” will be ignored, and it will always return the function “+”.

As an example, all the following will give 5, since f will always return the function “+” regardless of what it received as the first parameter, and the function “+” will operate on 2 and 3:

```
f “aaa”        2 3
f  904212      2 3
f  undefined   2 3
```

The type of f is:

```
f :: b -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

Note that “b” can be anything, as can be seen above.

Now for the actual function in question:

```
g = const id
```

This means that we “fixed” id as the first parameter, so as above, “g” ignores its first parameter and returns the function “id”.
In Haskell, we can go on ahead and provide the extra parameter to “id”, just like we did to (+) above, so for example all of these will return 42:

```
g  “aaa”     42
g  undefined 42
```

So “g” is function accepting two parameters, and always returning the second one, so its type is:

```
g = const id :: b -> a -> a
```

But wait a minute, I just made a giant leap there.  Shouldn't the type be:

```
b -> (a -> a)
```

since we just said that we accept anything and return “id”?

Well, yeah, except that in Haskell those parentheses can be omitted.
It also make sense since you can immediately supply the “id” function with the extra parameter it needs (as in the “const (+)” example above).

Answer (score 6):

The only way I finally grasped this was to imagine the sequence of steps Haskell takes in evaluating an expression like `const id 1 2`. First consider these statements:

> In Haskell, all functions are considered curried: That is, all functions in Haskell take just one argument. [1](https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying)
>
> Functional application though, associates to the left: f x y is really (f x) y. [1](https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying)

With this in mind, and seeing from above that `const` takes two arguments and `id` takes one, we can see these steps:

```
const id 1 2   -- Haskell evaluates 'const id' and returns a function (we can call it
               -- 'constId') which accepts one argument and always returns 'id'

constId 1 2    -- Haskell now evaluates 'constId 1', which as expected just returns 'id'

id 2           -- 'id' is now applied to 2, which just returns '2'

2              -- final result
```

Disclaimer: I am new to Haskell.