# What is the purpose of (const id) in this function?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to get deeper into the functional mindset and looking through solutions to exercises (99 problems).

The first problem is to create a function that returns the last element of the list.

I see the solution:

```
myLast = foldr1 (const id)
```

I understand that `foldr1` applies a function `f` to a list `l`

so if I plug it into an example:

```
myLast [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Which would be "translated to"

```
foldr1 (const id) [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Could someone explain to me what this (const id) is stepping through.  I tried researching `(const id)` in SO as well as Hoogle, but couldn't make much sense of it.  Would someone kindly step me through what is happening here?

Comment: Ok, now I feel a little silly. [Here's the exact duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745045/the-behavior-of-const-id).

Comment: Gah, I did a search too...Although your answer is a little more useful for me.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598076/how-is-this-function-equivalent-to-getting-the-last-item-in-a-list/18599375

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`const` and `id` are two separate functions that you can look up on Hoogle. Perhaps after that you can answer your question yourself, but I'll answer it anyway.

`const` is a function of two arguments that always returns its first argument.
`id` is a function of one argument that always returns its argument.

Therefore `(const id)` is a function of one argument that always returns `id`, or, in other words, a function of two arguments that always returns its second argument.

Now `foldr1` takes a function of two arguments `f elem accum` as the first argument, and applies it sequentially to the list, starting from the last element (using it as the initial value for the accumulator). In our case `f` will always return its second argument, so whatever `accum` was initialized with (last element of the list), it will stay the same over all iterations and will get returned.

Now you could use `seq` instead of `(const id)`, but `seq` is not lazy. Or you could just use `last` without writing your own function :)

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation.   It took me a couple times through to see the whole picture.   Hoogle had just given me the type definition for `const` and `id` which I didn't get the gist of immediately.  Gotta slow down sometimes

Comment: just a note that const id === flip const (by the way)